# .append() uma img tag?

Tags: jquery, html

Eu gostaria de inserir uma  tag usando append mas sempre que eu tento, ele tenta inserir uma imagem na div que eu desejo inserir apenas o texto, existe forma de conseguir?

```
<input type="file" multiple id="file-input" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<div id="id">

</div>
<script>
$("#file-input").change(function(){
  $("#id").empty();
  var names = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $(this).get(0).files.length; ++i) {
    var thisfile = $(this).get(0).files[i].name;
    $("#id").append("<img src='images/images/eventos/"+thisfile+"' /><br/>");
  }
})

</script>
```

Comment: O que queres dizer com _"inserir  uma tag"_? Não é uma imagem que queres?

Comment: @Sergio Quero escrever o codigo da tag de forma a aparecer por exemplo, <img src='images/images/eventos/1.jpg' />

Comment: Ainda não percebi o que queres dizer com "código da tag"... Queres inserir HTML sem que seja interpretado, é isso? para fica o HTML à vista do utilizador?

Comment: @Sergio Exatamente, existe forma de conseguir isso? Já usei `.html()` mas não funcionou.

Comment: Ok, então deves usar `.text()` em vez de `.html()`. Testa e diz se é isso que querias.

Comment: @Sergio Tentei mas apenas me apresenta a ultima imagem selecionada

Comment: Exato, vou dar uma resposta mais completa queria só certificar-me que o `.text` era o que procuravas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma solução bem simples, **alterando apenas um caractere do seu código**, seria substituir o sinal que abre a tag `<img>` "<" (menor que) por "`&lt;`". Desta forma o navegador irá tratar a tag como uma string:

```js
$("#file-input").change(function(){
  $("#id").empty();
  var names = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $(this).get(0).files.length; ++i) {
    var thisfile = $(this).get(0).files[i].name;
    $("#id").append("&lt;img src='images/images/eventos/"+thisfile+"' /><br/>");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" multiple id="file-input" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<div id="id">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

acho que o que voce quer é isso. Ou pelo menos foi o que entendi, me corrija caso esteja errado.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
   var imagem = $('#imag').val();
   $('body').text('<img src="'+imagem+'">')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="imag" placeholder="CAMINHO DA IMAGEM">
<button>inserir</button>
```

ATUALIZADO

```js
$('input').change(function(){
  var names = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < $(this).get(0).files.length; ++i) {
    var thisfile = $(this).get(0).files[i].name;
    $("#id").append(document.createTextNode("<img src='images/images/eventos/"+thisfile+"' /><br/>"));
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple>
  <div id="id"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Não é bem isso, eu queria selecionar as imagens com um input, e quando selecionasse, apresentasse não só o nome, mas <img src="nome_da_imagem.jpg" />

Comment: Acredito que eé so usar o `text`

Comment: @BrunoMoutinho Editei o codigo a cima, basta `executar` e ver se é isso mesmo

Comment: O problema é que isso não funciona num <input type="file" multiple> como eu queria, apenas apresenta o ultimo

Comment: Basta jogar em um for, me da um minuto, vou editar o codigo

Comment: @BrunoMoutinho Atualizei o codigo

Answer (score 0):

Como você está adicionando uma tag  passando seu respectivo src então ele irá carregar a imagem, seria melhor você dar um apend utilizando a tag p e o texto sendo o caminho da imagem conforme você quer.

```
<input type="file" multiple id="file-input" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<div id="id">

</div>
<script>
$("#file-input").change(function(){
  $("#id").empty();
  var names = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $(this).get(0).files.length; ++i) {
    var thisfile = $(this).get(0).files[i].name;
    $("#id").append("&lt;img src='images/images/eventos/"+thisfile+"'/>");
  }
})

</script>
```

Comment: Mas eu quereria também adicionar <img> e não só o src

Comment: entendi, basta colocar no inicio da tag no lugar de '<' o valor &lt; ficando o apende da seguinte forma:  $("#id").append(" &lt;img src=images/images/eventos/"+thisfile+"/>");

Comment: Mas se inserir na base de dados, irá inserir como < ou como &lt; ?

Comment: Dessa forma irá inserir &lt; porque  quando você buscar da base de dados para renderizar ele irá escrever a string da tag.

Answer (score 0):

Deves usar o `.text()` do jQuery assim:

```js
var files = ['la-la-la', 'le-le-le', 'li-li-li'];
// no teu caso podes usar 
// var files = $(this).get(0).files;

var text = files.map(file => "<img src='images/images/eventos/" + file + "' />").join("\n");
$("#id").text(text);

// e para criar quebra de linhas
$("#id").html($("#id").html().replace(/\n/g, '<br>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id"></div>
```